# Cocoa draw noise

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsview, custom-view

Is it possible to draw some noise on top of a rect I filled using NSRectFill? I need to make my app that draws a custom title bar look wonderful on 10.7 before release, and to make it look a little more like iTunes. I would love if this is possible using no images, but if I have to include a PNG or something as a mask, I'd be fine with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use drawing logic (drawing a lot of small rects, lines or other polygons), or use NSImage's drawing methods, like for instance: `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:`

Comment: To create the noise image to draw, you can read bytes from /dev/random and create a CGImage from them as grayscale pixels. Use a low alpha, 0.1 or even less, when drawing the grayscale noise onto your background.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I'd use the random noise generator included with Core Image. A custom one with /dev/random would probably be slower.

Comment: @Chuck: Ah, I searched the CIFR for “noise” and found nothing that generates it. Searching again, this time for “random”, turned up CIRandomGenerator: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRandomGenerator You would want to use it with CIColorMonochrome, with its color set to black, to make the output random grayscale pixels and not random colored pixels.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using CIRandomGenerator, and then just drawing it over the gradient I drew before with a 0.175f opacity. Works like a charm and looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Tristan Seifert: That might be a little strong. As a general rule, such things (and this goes for animations as well) should be just a little less than noticeable. Playing with it in Opacity, even 0.1 might be too strong; 0.075 seems to work well.